# How to solve error like Exception in thread "TimerQueue" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException in java?

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication

I am making application of serial communication on ARM processor for SerialPort(/dev/ttyS0).
My Processor is armv7l(512 RAM, Linux OS(debian.imag) ). I got some error which I can't understand or why it occurred some time(not every time)? My code and error are below. So if you have any idea or suggestion then please tell me.

```
//Imports were here...

public class SerialCommandApp extends JPanel {

    public static javax.swing.JTextField inpuText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel inputLbl;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel outPutLbl;
    public static javax.swing.JTextArea outPuttextArea;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tempLbl;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel tempShowLbl;
    public static javax.swing.JTextArea temptextArea;
    public static boolean inputFlag = false;
    public OutputStream out = null;
    String command = "t0?\n";
    int count=1;
    public Timer tmr = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            if (count == 0) {
                sendCommand();
            }
            count--;
        }
    });

    public void sendCommand() {

        final Thread SendThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                count = 1;
                try {
                    out.write(command.getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SerialCommandApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        };
        SendThread.setDaemon(true);
        SendThread.start();
    }
    public LaserCommandApp() {
        setComponents();
        connect("/dev/ttyS0");
        tmr.start();
    }
    private void setComponents() {
        tempLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel("Temperature :");
        tempShowLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel("Label");
        inputLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel("InPut :");
        inpuText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        outPutLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel("OutPut :");
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        outPuttextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        temptextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea(40000, 10);
        this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255));
        tempLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        tempShowLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N        
        inputLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        inpuText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        inpuText.setText(""); // NOI18N
        inpuText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                inpuTextKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });
        outPutLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        outPuttextArea.setColumns(20);
        outPuttextArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(outPuttextArea);
        temptextArea.setColumns(20);
        temptextArea.setRows(10);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(temptextArea);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(inputLbl).addContainerGap(482, Short.MAX_VALUE)).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING).addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(outPutLbl).addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 253, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 102, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(inpuText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 122, Short.MAX_VALUE).addComponent(tempLbl).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addComponent(tempShowLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 77, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))).addGap(36, 36, 36)))));
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap().addComponent(inputLbl).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(inpuText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(tempLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addComponent(tempShowLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(43, 43, 43).addComponent(outPutLbl).addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 154, Short.MAX_VALUE)).addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(3, 3, 3).addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 222, Short.MAX_VALUE))).addContainerGap()));

    }
        private void inpuTextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            try {
                inputFlag = true;
                String str = inpuText.getText() + "\n";
                out.write(str.getBytes());
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Errore at enter press button");
            }
        }
    }
    public final void connect(String portName) {
        try {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
            if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
            } else {
                CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);
                if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
                    SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
                    InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                    out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                    Thread inputThread = (new Thread(new SerialReader(in)));
                    inputThread.setDaemon(true);
                    inputThread.start();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchPortException npx) {
            System.out.println("No Such Port is Available");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occure at connecting to port");
        }
    }
    public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {
        String str = "";
        String fullString = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        public SerialReader(InputStream in1) {
            this.in = in1;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;
            try {
                while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                    str = new String(buffer, 0, len);
                     fullString = fullString + str;

                    if (fullString.endsWith("\n")) {

                        if (SerialCommandApp.inputFlag) {
                            SerialCommandApp.inputFlag = false;
                            SerialCommandApp.outPuttextArea.append(fullString);
                            //SerialCommandApp.outPuttextArea.append("\n");
                        } else {
                            SerialCommandApp.temptextArea.append(fullString);
                           // SerialCommandApp.temptextArea.append("\n");
                            SerialCommandApp.tempShowLbl.setText(fullString);
                        }
                        fullString = "";
                    } 

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Errore at reading data");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.add(new LaserCommandApp());
        jFrame.setSize(500, 400);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

## Error:

```
enter code here
Exception in thread "TimerQueue" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:155)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1260)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:460)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.awtUnlock(SunToolkit.java:245)
    at sun.java2d.x11.X11Renderer.fillRect(X11Renderer.java:214)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.fillRect(ValidatePipe.java:76)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.fillRect(SunGraphics2D.java:2321)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintBackground(BasicTextUI.java:658)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(BasicTextUI.java:728)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(BasicTextUI.java:883)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(BasicTextUI.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:769)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5212)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5160)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4971)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:100)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetState(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:566)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:290)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.addTimer(TimerQueue.java:135)
    at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(TimerQueue.java:187)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception in thread "AWT-XAWT" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.compareAndSetState(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:566)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:290)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.awtLock(SunToolkit.java:237)
    at sun.awt.X11.XBaseWindow.ungrabInput(XBaseWindow.java:883)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.run(XToolkit.java:675)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.run(XToolkit.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public OutputStream out = null;
```

Is never initialized. You're having a NullPointerException.

Comment: @Asier Aranbarri , thanks for reply. but in my code i got out(OutPutStream) object from connect("/dev/ttyS0") method. so it was not null after connect with Serial port.

Comment: But if the port is not avaliable, then you don't get into the logic of the connect method, the program won't crash (because you have an if statement) and the thread will probably try to make something with out. It may not be the problem, as you said, but well, I think it could help you :  )

Comment: @AsierAranbarri ok.I will check that condition in my code and try to make my code such universal, so it will run after the no serial port is available or used serial port event.